# Open app on a chosen virtual desktop

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

I have a cmd script that will launch multiple instance a the same program over a long time.

I takes quite a long time, so I would like to be able to do something else during this time, without having the program pop-up in front every 30 second.

I though I could use virtual desktops. My script with the automatic launches on desktop 1, and I work on desktop 2.

The problem is that each new instance of the program start on the current desktop. Is there a way have "this program shall start on this desktop", or "program go to the same desktop has the cmd that launched it"? (or any other solution to this problem...)

Note that I can't change the cmd script itself, it's managed by my company.

###### Edit:

In essence, it is something like this:

```
timeout 5
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,4) DO (
  notepad++
  timeout 1
  taskkill /IM notepad++.exe
  timeout 1
)
```

Launch this on desktop1, switch to desktop2. Is it possible to have notepad++ be launched in desktop1 ; and to not see it in desktop2?

Answer (score 0):

You may use
[VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk)
to launch a programs on a given virtual desktop

The run command looks like:

```
    vdesk 2 command
```

Comment: Yes but that requires to modify the script, which I can't. I can run cmd with vdesk, when cmd calls another program it spawn in the current desktop

Comment: This requires more info about the script.

Comment: Well I really don't have some, and I definitely CAN'T modify it. Here (https://pastebin.com/yCrU1xy4) is a script that does the same: it spawn a notepad++ multiple time. Is it possible for the notepad++ windows to open on a not current desktop without modifying this script?

Comment: The only solution I can see is to use AutoHotKey with [VD.ahk](https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk#readme) and a script that does [WinWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinWait.htm) waiting for the process and then moving it immediately to the other desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution could be the way you launch your subsequent scripts.

If you launch them in the same CMD instance, rather than in a new CMD instance, there will not be any additional popups at all, and you can even keep the CMD window in a minimized state in your current desktop if you want.

Given that you have not posted your script, or at least the part that generates the new popup, its impossible for me to assist you with this part until you edit your question and provide part of the script that generates these popups.

Comment: I don't launch subsequent script, I launch a graphical. I edited my question with an example to be clearer

Comment: Given you cannot alter the script, that makes this impossible anyway. Otherwise, you could maybe launch the programs minimized. Would still steal your focus so is not ideal, but this is not going to work for you then. I'll keep the answer here for someone who might need it.